# Interacting with Spring Boot + DynamoDB

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, amazon-dynamodb

I'm struggling to learn how I go about building, packaging, and deploying a Spring REST API locally so that I can interact with it? Ideally, I'd just like to GET and POST data as practice -- specifically integrating with DynamoDB.

I've cloned [this DynamoDB project](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-data-dynamodb) and built it using `mvn package` so that I have a jar file. I moved the jar file to the webapp directory of Apache and started the server, but I cannot interact with the API in any way. The project is structured as follows:

[image]

Once Apache is running with the jar in the webapp directory, I've tried accessing the API at:

- http://localhost:8080/
- http://localhost:8080/springbootapp (from `server.contextPath=/springbootapp` in application.properties)

Each gives a 404 error. And yes, DynamoDB is running locally. So what do I need to do differently? How can I deploy and access this API locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project you have cloned is a spring boot project, hence you can use `mvn spring-boot:run` to run the application locally.You can also run it by running the `com.baeldung.Application` class as a java application from the IDE. For more details on how to run a spring boot app you can follow [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html) link. Spring boot parent has a dependency on the embedded tomcat, which will run the application.

Additionally if you want to deploy the application as a war the [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) shows how to do it.